# Organise endnotes by chapter titles

Tags: titlesec, endnotes, enotez

I am trying to use `enotez` to organise ("split") my endnotes by chapter and use the relevant chapter titles as headings (ideally centred) as demonstrated below and include the pagination the notes refer to in the header (e.g., *Notes to pages 25-37*), using `titlesec`.

```
Notes

                     CHAPTER I: TeX

1. TeX is a typesetting system (or a "formatting system").
2. TeX was designed and mostly written by Donald Knuth.

                   CHAPTER 2: WYSIWYG

1. *WYSIWYG* stands for What You See Is What You Get.
2. The phrase implies a user interface that allows the user to view something very similar to the end result.
3. *WYSIWYG* means that the display simulates the appearance and represents the effect of fonts and line breaks on the final pagination using a specific printer configuration.
```

The code thus far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
    \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{18pt}}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
    \newpagestyle{main}{\sethead[\thepage][\textit{\thetitle}][] % even
        {}{\textit{\chaptertitle}}{\thepage}} % odd
    \pagestyle{main}

\usepackage{enotez}
    \setenotez{backref=true, totoc, split=chapter, split-title={\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ <ref>: <title>}}}
    \NewSplitTitleTag{title}{\nameref{ch:<split-level-id>}}

\begin{document}
%frontmatter etc.
    \mainmatter
        \chapter{TeX}
           When the second edition\endnote{TeX is a typesetting system (or a "formatting system").} was published, in 1976, the whole book had to be typeset again because the Monotype technology had been largely replaced by phototypesetting, and the original fonts were no longer available. When Knuth\endnote{TeX was designed and mostly written by Donald Knuth.} received the galley proofs of the new book on 30 March 1977, he found them inferior. 
        \chapter{WYSIWYG}
           Modern software does a good job of optimizing the screen display for a particular type of output. For example, a word processor is optimized for output to a typical printer. The software often emulates the resolution of the printer in order to get as close as possible to WYSIWYG\endnote{WYSIWYG stands for What You See Is What You Get.}. However, that is not the main attraction of WYSIWYG\endnote{The phrase implies a user interface that allows the user to view something very similar to the end result.}, which is the ability of the user to be able to visualize what they are producing\endnote{WYSIWYG means that the display simulates the appearance and represents the effect of fonts and line breaks on the final pagination using a specific printer configuration}. 
\backmatter
        \cleardoublepage
            \printendnotes
            \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.5em}}
\end{document}
```

Example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: notes #1]
[image: notes #2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book,`report`and`article` classes) with its own facilities for end notes. Below I have modified your MWE to give what I think you want.

```
% endnotesprob.tex  SE 535808 

%\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\makepagenote % for memoir's endnotes
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{blindtext}
    \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{18pt}}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
    \newpagestyle{main}{\sethead[\thepage][\textit{\thetitle}][] % even
        {}{\textit{\chaptertitle}}{\thepage}} % odd
    \pagestyle{main}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{comment}

\usepackage{enotez}
    \setenotez{backref=true, totoc, split=chapter, split-title={\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ <ref>: <title>}}}
    \NewSplitTitleTag{title}{\nameref{ch:<split-level-id>}}
\end{comment}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%frontmatter etc.
    \mainmatter
        \chapter{TeX}
           When the second edition\pagenote{TeX is a typesetting system (or a "formatting system").} was published, in 1976, the whole book had to be typeset again because the Monotype technology had been largely replaced by phototypesetting, and the original fonts were no longer available. When Knuth\pagenote{TeX was designed and mostly written by Donald Knuth.} received the galley proofs of the new book on 30 March 1977, he found them inferior. 
        \chapter{WYSIWYG}
           Modern software does a good job of optimizing the screen display for a particular type of output. For example, a word processor is optimized for output to a typical printer. The software often emulates the resolution of the printer in order to get as close as possible to WYSIWYG\pagenote{WYSIWYG stands for What You See Is What You Get.}. However, that is not the main attraction of WYSIWYG\pagenote{The phrase implies a user interface that allows the user to view something very similar to the end result.}, which is the ability of the user to be able to visualize what they are producing\pagenote{WYSIWYG means that the display simulates the appearance and represents the effect of fonts and line breaks on the final pagination using a specific printer configuration}. 
\backmatter
        \cleardoublepage
%            \printendnotes
\printpagenotes % for memoir's endnotes
            \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.5em}}
\end{document}
```

To avoid clashes with other packages `memoir` uses the macro `\pagenote` instead of `\endnote` for endnotes. In the preamble you have to put `\makepagenote` to get endnotes and use `\printpagenotes` for when you want them printed. The manual (`texdoc memoir`) section **17.4 Endnotes** describes many ways of adjusting the appearance of the endnotes both in the main text and in the listing.